# How to configure NuxtJS build to customize file paths without modifying router options?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have developed an SPA (ssr: false) using NuxtJS. After build, file paths to javascript and css files are relative to domain’s root folder and not dist folder. for example `<script src="/_nuxt/e247009.js"></script>` which causes the browser to throw the error

> "The resource from "*the url*" was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)."

My `url` paths inside css fonts-face also have this problem.

I could solve the error using this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61638555/8488702 by setting the router option like so:

```
router: {
  base: './'
}
```

But now another problem arises and that's that when I load `index.html` which is in the root of the project nuxt router shows the error

> This page could not be found

How can I customize file paths without changing router option so that the router won't break?

Comment: router base could be `'/'`. Why not use your dist folder as root?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos this is the default that causes mim-type error

Comment: that could be a server error, are you using a local server?

Comment: @HansFelixRamos Yes, these errors occur in local enviroment.  Right now I uploaded dist folder contents to the root of server and it's working fine. Would you please explain why is this happening? thank you man.

Comment: For production, you do have a build to do (either with `yarn generate` or `yarn build`), hence you need to serve the generated `dist` directory. Not sure why you do have any error on local env (using `yarn dev` right?) but IMO, your error is totally not related to any path or so. And also, the `/_nuxt/e247009.js` path is totally fine, this is coming from Webpack's cached version located in `.nuxt` directory. A MIME-type issue is mainly caused when you do serve a format that is not expected.

Comment: Did you tried to build it locally and run it? `yarn generate` (or `yarn build`) and `yarn start`? Also, can you please share your `nuxt.config.js` file?

Comment: @kissu I loaded index.html locally using web storm local server cause it's just static. and got these errors.

Comment: You should definitely not use an IDE's server, especially for some SSR'ed app. Just use the native baked-in ready-to-go webpack-server provided by Nuxt. Will be superior in every aspect, and less error-prone as you can see. Go to your app and run `yarn dev` or `npm run dev` depending on which one you do use. Also, what do you mean by `it's just static`? You do have `target: 'static'`? It does not make the project runbable like any regular `index.html` file on the dev environment. As you can think, `/_nuxt/e247009.js` is not a static usual js file.

Comment: @kissu Yeah I know how to run project locally but I thought cause these are static files I could simulate server like this. And Yes, I meant `target: static` when I said static. Why `/_nuxt/e247009.js` is not a usual js file? I'm feeling terrible not understanding this after these years of experience :(

Comment: No pressure man, everybody learns daily. Having 20 years of experience is not making you a code God because it's too broad and you can't learn 100% of things. :) So, on production you can run the files as they are vanilla HTML/CSS **purely static files**. On development, since Nuxt is a modern JS framework (same goes for Vue), it does rely on bundlers (atm Webpack v4) for all the local environment features like HMR, cache-invalidation, SASS pre-processors etc... But it's far from being basic files. Webpack is doing all the heavy lifting but you **need** to run your project with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP ran the project with his Webstorm IDE thinking that `target: 'static'` will allow it to work on local env. Even if it works on production because there are actual static files generated (those can indeed be hosted on a CDN), modern development is not as simple.

Hence, we do need to use the `webpack-dev-server` baked-in local server to support all the great features of modern development (HMR, file-hashing, SASS etc...).

Running `yarn dev` (or `npm run dev`) will allow for a proper working project, with an already configured Webpack v4 configuration done for you by the Nuxt core team.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me man. I opened index.html that is inside dist folder which works fine on the server but not on the local server. (aren't files inside dist folder  "actual static files"?

Comment: @amirify you're planing to build your whole app each time you do an update to a single file? As stated, it works on production (aka if you build it). If you want to run a local server, you need to run webpack.

Comment: Ofcourse not. I'm just wondering why built files don't work on local env.

Comment: @amirify if you try my repo here: https://github.com/kissu/so-date-fns-calendar You can `yarn generate` it. Then, go to `/dist` in a CLI, open it with VScode (important to open VScode in the `/dist` directory and not at the root project!), with the Live Server extension (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), you should arrive on a full static version of my app once running it with `>Live Server: Open with Live Server`. I'm pretty sure that Webstorm can achieve this too! This is pretty much what Netlify/Vercel are doing too, since it's fully static.